# How to solve Visual studio C# windows form UI lost system theming?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a windows form for several months with Visual studio C# 2019, and yesterday while i was moving some elements around in order to add a new one, the UI got suddenly a different looking after execution, and i cant get back to how it looked originally, as well as i cant figure out what i changed to make this happening.

This is how it was and always have been looking before:

[image]

And this is how it started to be looking from yesterday:

[image]

Anyone knows what could have possibly changed to get visual studio compiling something that looks so ugly ? (While nothing changed in the builder, it looks like that only at execution time)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This look is old Windows 95 native GUI without theming introduced with XP.

If themes are not disabled in Windows system settings, check if `Program.cs` have in this order :

```
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new FormTest());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the render property of the form or the controls itself:
[Custom Control Painting and Rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=netframework-4.8)

If you are not using source control like GIT or SVN, I strongly suggest it.  You can then compare your last commit and see what has changed.  If you are using source control when you do a diff anything jumps out at you?